# Run HTML file on HTTPS local server

Tags: node.js, express, localhost

I'm trying to run an aframe html webAR script which requires a HTTPS server due to camera permissions.
Following the below link, I have setup a HTTPS server using mkcert, create the index.js with the code to run it, and then run it using `node index.js` and access via `https://localhost:3000`

Tutorial: https://www.mariokandut.com/how-to-set-up-ssl-locally-in-node-js/

But I now want to run an index.html file on that HTTPS server.  How would I do that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to [serve static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: @Phil thank you!

Comment: There are lots of ways to solve the HTTPS problem as a VR Dev.  See https://aframe.wiki//development for a range of different solutions.